# libapache2-mod-php7.0 not working on Debian Stretch

Tags: debian, apache-httpd, php, openssl

I am trying to install PHP 7.0 on Debian 9.4. When I install `libapache2-mod-php7.0` I get the following error.

```
    Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so)
```

If i run ldd for `libphp7.0.so` I get

```
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffce37eb000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007fbb967b7000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007fbb965a0000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007fbb96386000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007fbb96113000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007fbb95f0b000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fbb95c07000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fbb95a03000)
    libnsl.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007fbb957eb000)
    libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007fbb95430000)
    libssl.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007fbb951c4000)
    libcrypto.so.1.1 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007fbb94dc8000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbb94a29000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fbb9480c000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbb97026000)
    libicui18n.so.57 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicui18n.so.57 (0x00007fbb94392000)
    libicuuc.so.57 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicuuc.so.57 (0x00007fbb93fea000)
    libicudata.so.57 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libicudata.so.57 (0x00007fbb9256d000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007fbb92347000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fbb91fc5000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fbb91dae000)
```

If I run `ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ | grep crypto` I get

```
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  4811326 Mar 29 06:51 libcrypto.a
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root 11735850 Jun  5  2017 libcrypto++.a
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       13 Jun  5  2017 libcryptopp.a ->                          libcrypto++.a
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       14 Jun  5  2017 libcryptopp.so ->libcrypto++.so
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Jun  5  2017 libcryptopp.so.6 -> libcrypto++.so.6
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Mar 29 06:51 libcrypto.so ->libcrypto.so.1.1
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       20 Jun  5  2017 libcrypto++.so ->libcrypto++.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       16 Apr 14 16:09 libcrypto.so.1.0.0 ->libcrypto.so.1.1
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  2492224 Mar 29 07:10 libcrypto.so.1.0.2
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  2066816 Apr 14 15:48 libcrypto.so.1.1
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       20 Jun  5  2017 libcrypto++.so.6 ->libcrypto++.so.6.0.0
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root  3667096 Jun  5  2017 libcrypto++.so.6.0.0
    lrwxrwxrwx  1 root root       18 Aug  9  2017 libk5crypto.so.3 ->libk5crypto.so.3.1
    -rw-r--r--  1 root root   203656 Aug  9  2017 libk5crypto.so.3.1
```

I can provide any more information that might help someone point me in the right direction. I am at a loss here. It seems like I have the correct version of libcrypto, but PHP won't go for it.

Answer (score 0):

Just looking at the rather long error message:

> ```
> Syntax error on line 141 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 3 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.0.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so into server: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_0' not found (required by /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp7.0.so)
> ```

One can easily get to the root cause:

> ```
> OPENSSL_1_1_0 not found (required...)
> ```

---

In other words, either you have no version of `openssl` package installed, or it is out-of-date.

---

You can verify this by running:

```
apt-cache policy openssl
```

In my case, where it is installed and up-to-date, it shows:

```
openssl:
  Installed: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2
  Candidate: 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2
  Version table:
 *** 1.1.0f-3+deb9u2 500
        500 http://security.debian.org stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1.0f-3+deb9u1 500
        500 http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: yeah i had the same output. the correct version was installed (you can see that from the ldd output and the ls). i ended up just purge-ing everything starting over. i think there was some arcane conflict between different version of openssl (i had an older version installed for something else)